# Converting to ADO.net from ADODB recordset and having difficulty figuring out what the problem is

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, adodb

```vb
If gItemCnt > 0 Then
    For iRow = 1 To gItemCnt
        sSpecies = Mid(gItemArray(iRow), 15, 2)
        bFound = False
        For x = 1 To rsSum.RecordCount
            If rsSum.Fields("Species").Value = sSpecies Then
                bFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
            rsSum.MoveNext()
        Next x
        If bFound = False Then
            rsSum.AddNew()
            rsSum.Fields("SpeciesSort").Value = GetDesc(gSpeciesCodes, sSpecies, 3, 1)
            rsSum.Fields("Species").Value = sSpecies
        End If
        lFootage = cPrint.GetItemArrayFootage(iRow, True)
        rsSum.Fields("MTDShipFootage").Value = rsSum.Fields("MTDShipFootage").Value + lFootage
        rsSum.Update()
        rsSum.MoveFirst()
    Next iRow
End If
```

Above is the old code, below one of the many things I have tried but my index's get out of whack and throw an error that index 'whatever number' does not exist.

```vb
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim lFootage As Integer
Dim iRow As Short
Dim lPlcHoldr As Long
Dim y As Integer = -1
x = -1

If gItemCnt > 0 Then
    For iRow = 1 To gItemCnt
        sSpecies = Mid(gItemArray(iRow), 15, 2)
        bFound = False
        Dim my_row As DataRow

        For Each my_row In dtSum.Rows
            If my_row("Species") = sSpecies Then
                bFound = True
                y += 1
                Exit For
            End If
            x += 1
        Next

        'For x = 0 To dtSum.Rows.Count - 1
        '    If dtSum.Rows(x)("Species") = sSpecies Then
        '        bFound = True
        '        Exit For
        '    End If
        'Next x
        Dim r As DataRow = dtSum.NewRow
        If bFound = False Then
            'Dim r As DataRow = dtSum.NewRow
            r("SpeciesSort") = GetDesc(gSpeciesCodes, sSpecies, 3, 1)
            r("Species") = sSpecies
            r("DlyShipFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("DlyRemanFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("DlyClaimFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("MTDShipFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("MTDRemanFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("MTDClaimFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("MTDClaimFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            dtSum.Rows.Add(r)
        End If
        If bFound = True Then
            x = y
            lFootage = cPrint.GetItemArrayFootage(iRow, True)
            dtSum.Rows(x)("MTDShipFootage") = dtSum.Rows(x)("MTDShipFootage") + lFootage
            daSum.Update(ds, "tblTmpDlySum")
            Debug.WriteLine(lFootage)
        Else
            x += 1
            lFootage = cPrint.GetItemArrayFootage(iRow, True)
            r("MTDShipFootage") = r("MTDShipFootage") + lFootage
            Debug.WriteLine(lFootage)
        End If

    Next iRow
End If
```

Can anyone see where I am messing up? I am sure it is with the `x` and/or `y` that I am adding in there. I am very new to vb.net and coding all together, since December 2022 is when I was put in a position to help translate all our legacy apps from vb6 to .net and I figured I should just update everything to ado.net while updating everything else. However, this section is a little more complicated to me. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: `I am very new to vb.net and coding all together, since December 2022` - we do welcome fellow time travelers here.

Comment: Can you be more precise on the errore message received? Even a literal translation could help us to identify the problem. Beside, at first look, you seem to use a loop over an array starting at index 1. Not true in VB.NET. Indexes start at zero and you should loop over the array length - 1

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 3.'
 from this line:   dtSum.Rows(x)("MTDShipFootage") = dtSum.Rows(x)("MTDShipFootage") + lFootage

Comment: @GSerg lol, 2020. but might as well be 2022 with how green and lost I feel sometimes.

Comment: @Steve Are you saying iRow should be "0"? For iRow = 0 to gItemCnt -1?

Comment: Yes, if you are looping over an array the first index is 0 and the last valid item is at array.length - 1

Comment: I think I know what the problem is in my code. I have nothing replacing the rsSum.MoveFirst() command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If gItemCnt > 0 Then

    For iRow = 1 To gItemCnt
        sSpecies = Mid(gItemArray(iRow), 15, 2)
        bFound = False

        For x = 0 To dtSum.Rows.Count - 1
            If dtSum.Rows(x)("Species") = sSpecies Then
                bFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
        Dim r As DataRow = dtSum.NewRow
        If bFound = False Then
            'Dim r As DataRow = dtSum.NewRow
            r("SpeciesSort") = GetDesc(gSpeciesCodes, sSpecies, 3, 1)
            r("Species") = sSpecies
            r("DlyShipFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("DlyRemanFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("DlyClaimFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("MTDShipFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("MTDRemanFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("MTDClaimFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            r("MTDClaimFootage") = lPlcHoldr
            dtSum.Rows.Add(r)
        End If
        If bFound = True Then

            lFootage = cPrint.GetItemArrayFootage(iRow, True)
            dtSum.Rows(x)("MTDShipFootage") = dtSum.Rows(x)("MTDShipFootage") + lFootage
            daSum.Update(ds, "tblTmpDlySum")
            Debug.WriteLine(lFootage)
            x = 0
        Else

            lFootage = cPrint.GetItemArrayFootage(iRow, True)
            r("MTDShipFootage") = r("MTDShipFootage") + lFootage
            Debug.WriteLine(lFootage)
            x = 0
        End If

    Next iRow
End If
```

This is what got it working. Thanks for your help. I guess having someone and somewhere to talk things out really made me see what was going on. Reseting x back to 0 allowed the for loop to start back at the first row in the datatable.